# how to avoid request forgery on android

Tags: android, security, request

I have an Android app that POST and GET JSON from web services I published, I want to secure the app requests avoiding things like request forgery. The channel is already protected with HTTPS and also I am encrypting sensible data on JSON string, but what I want is an advice on which technique/method to use for secure requests, I’ve been thinking in something like session tokens, but I haven’t found a reliable solution yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is only one way.  It is impossible for your server to know if a request has been forged - unless, the client has some secret which only the server knows and cannot be forged.  That secret is a certificate issued by you, not a public root authority, which you give your clients.  Of course, they might share the certificate but that's a question of trust.  If it really needs to be secure, it should not leave the server.